# Wav to MP3 Conversion

Tags: delphi, mp3, wav, wave, converters

I'm making a program in Delphi, which records the audio from vinyl records, then detects and separates the different tracks from each other. My problem is I can't convert the recorded wav files to mp3. I have tried to use LAME, but that gives me an mp3 file that plays to slow (eg. I start with a 1 min wav and it lands up as a 5 min mp3)

Please can you suggest source code or components with which I can convert wav files to mp3s.

Comment: You can enjoy your favorite music 5x times longer, that's awesome! No, seriously, LAME encoder works pretty fine (I know it, we are in relationship :-), I would suspect the way you are recording vinyls to wav. Have you heard them ?

Comment: LAME works very well. You are probably using it wrong. Without code we can't tell.

Comment: Perhaps you're configuring the wrong sample rates? If you turn a 48KHz wav into a 8Khz mp3 without resampling, your result will play too slow. If you show some code, or upload your wav+mp3 somewhere, we can probably tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I got the mp3 playing at more or less the right speed, but i did it through trial and error, is there a way to get the sample rate from the wav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AudioLab from Mitov.

http://www.mitov.com/html/audiolab.html